# Scheme - Access Data Pairs in List

Tags: scheme, racket

I am brand-new to Scheme (using Dr. Racket), and this is a homework assignment, so please no outright answers. I've been trying to find a solution online, but have not found one that is satisfactory.

I am writing a procedure that will take one argument - a list of pairs. I then need to find the difference between each pair of two numbers using abs, then add up the differences for all pairs.

My code is below.

```
(define example2 '((2 -7) (-4 -20) (7 7) (-13 2)))

(define get-difference      
  (lambda (lyst)
    (apply plus (abs(list-ref lyst 0)) (abs(list-ref lyst 1)))))

(define total-error
  (lambda list-of-pairs
    (apply plus (map get-difference list-of-pairs))))
```

I am having trouble with two things (I think):
Accessing each pair of data through the whole list
Using abs appropriately for each pair in the list.

I can use get-difference if I pass it two numbers,

```
(define get-difference      
  (lambda (x y)
    (+ (abs x) (abs y))))
```

but I am trying to pass a list to it instead. From another assignment, I used a get-num function, and it worked correctly - however, this approach did not seem to work for my issue:

```
(define get-num
  (lambda (lyst)
    (list-ref lyst 1)))

(define average-grade
  (lambda (list-of-grades)
    (/ (apply plus (map get-num list-of-grades)) (length list-of-grades))))
```

Any hints or suggestions are appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: I forgot to mention - I am not allowed to use recursion or looping.

Comment: seems like a problem well suited to be solved via folding

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! We haven't talked about folding in class, so I can't use it. I will, however, look into it for future use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, I think the `get-difference` function is incorrectly defined. Shouldn't it be like this instead?

```
(define get-difference      
  (lambda (x y)
    (abs (- x y))))
```

Back to the main problem. You're on the right track, using `apply`, `map`, `list-ref` will work, but you're combining them in the wrong way. Try this:

```
(define total-error
  (lambda (list-of-pairs)
    (apply + (map (lambda (pair) ; each element in the list is a pair
                    (get-difference (list-ref pair 0)
                                    (list-ref pair 1)))
                  list-of-pairs))))
```

Alternatively, we can do the difference-then-addition in a single step, using `foldl`:

```
(define total-error
  (lambda (list-of-pairs)
    (foldl (lambda (pair sum)
             (+ (get-difference (list-ref pair 0)
                                (list-ref pair 1))
                sum))
           0
           list-of-pairs)))
```

Comment: Thank you! I have been confused about where to use apply and map correctly. So, just to make sure I'm clear, list-of-pairs is the argument being passed in to map, and the get difference function is called on each pair (which is passed to lambda as the parameter). I appreciate your help!

Comment: @AbigailB that's right. And _after_ `map` has finished, `apply +` adds all the differences